# Run VBA Macro in Excel when a particular formula recalculates

Tags: vba, excel

I am far from great at macros in Excel and could really use some guidance. Need to run a simple macro that looks like this:

```
Public Sub CopyReplaceValue(rng1 As String)

Dim str1 As String
Dim str2 As String
Dim str3 As String
Dim rng2 As Integer

On Error GoTo LetsContinue

str1 = "N" ''this is your FRZ column
str2 = Range(rng1).Row ''Row number of updated cell
str3 = str1 & str2 ''FRZ cell to be changed

rng2 = Range(str3).Value 
If Sgn(Range(rng1)) <> Sgn(rng2) Then    
Range(str3).Value = 0    
ElseIf Abs(Range(rng1).Value) <= Abs(rng2) Then    
Range(str3).Value = Range(rng1).Value

End If    
LetsContinue:    
Exit Sub  
End Sub
```

Now the tricky part is how to call this macro when I need it to be. I want `rng1` to be a cell from a range set by me, I then need an event to trigger the call.

The problem is that using `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` does not seem to work since the finished sheet will only change when RTD links and formulas update. That event only seems to update when I manually change a value in the range, which isn't something that I will ever do when the sheet is complete.

Is there a way to call this macro when a cell within this range re-calculates and/or changes via formula, without a person touching the sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the `Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()`.

You may need to create some to trigger or not your macro inside the function.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I have tried using that but so far can't come up with a way to keep it from ending up in an endless loop.

Comment: @CraigKey You would need to set `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the start of your code (and reset it to `True` at the end).  That will stop any events firing  while your code is running (i.e. a calculation due to changes made by your code won't re-fire the `Worksheet_Calculate` event.)